# how to replace values of dictionary with another dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Hi I have two lists which contain some dictionary with their values

```
list1 = [{'val-1': 0, 'val-2': 0, 'val-3': 0}, {'val-1': 0, 'val-2': 0, 'val-3': 0}, {'val-4': 0, 
'val-5': 0, 'val-6': 0}]

list2 = [{'val-1': 90, 'val-4': 89, 'val-3': 99}, {'val-2': 88, 'val-6': 55, 'val-1':100}]
```

The desired output would be something like this

```
output: [{'val-1': 90, 'val-2': 88, 'val-3': 99}, {'val-1': 90, 'val-2': 88, 'val-3': 99}, {'val-4': 
89,'val-5': 0, 'val-6': 55}]
```

How could I make this replacement?

what I did form list2 I select each dictionary and compare and replace the values present in list1 all dictionary

but I didn't get the correct output

Comment: So you use only `'val-1': 90` and not `'val-1': 100` ? That is strange. So please edit your post and explain better what happen

Answer (score 0):

From the `list2` you may build a unique `dict` that holds the transformation mappings, if you have more than once occurence of a key you have 2 choices

1. keep first occurence, don't overwrite
2. keep last, overwrite each time

For keepfirst

```
list2 = [{'val-1': 90, 'val-4': 89, 'val-3': 99}, {'val-2': 88, 'val-6': 55, 'val-1': 100}]

# 1. Keep first (in fact overwrite but do backward)
update_dict = {k: v for d in list2[::-1] for k, v in d.items()}
# 2. Keep last
update_dict = {k: v for d in list2 for k, v in d.items()}
```

Then rebuild the original `list1` structure with list and dict comprehension, using the `update_dict`

```
result = [{k: update_dict.get(k, v) for k, v in subdict.items()}
          for subdict in list1]
print(result)
```

---

With `1. keep first`

```
[{'val-1': 90, 'val-2': 88, 'val-3': 99}, {'val-1': 90, 'val-2': 88, 'val-3': 99}, {'val-4': 89, 'val-5': 0, 'val-6': 55}]
```

With `2. keep last` (changes `val-1`)

```
[{'val-1': 100, 'val-2': 88, 'val-3': 99}, {'val-1': 100, 'val-2': 88, 'val-3': 99}, {'val-4': 89, 'val-5': 0, 'val-6': 55}]
```